# Does one include inflation when computing elasticity?

Tags: reference-request, elasticity

I am attempting to compute the price elasticity of a good with the help of a time series, and am unsure whether to correct the prices for inflation. Is there a standard argument for one or the other option? I would also be grateful for a reference.

Comment: Elasticities are partial derivatives -- so to estimate them you need to hold all other factors fixed! That would include the prices of other goods

Comment: @afreelunch this deserves a shot at credit for being the answer, because it is.  :)

Comment: @afreelunch Concise and understandable. I would accept this as an answer if you wish to post it as such.

Comment: @Anthony OK, will do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elasticities are partial derivatives -- so to estimate them you need to hold all other factors fixed! That would include the prices of other goods.